# Time exec in a subshell

Tags: bash, stderr, io-redirection

```
$ time (exec -a foo echo hello)
hello
```

It seems as though `stderr` (where `time` writes its output) leaks somewhere;  obviously this is not what I intended.

My question could be phrased in generic terms as "**why isn't the standard error stream written on the terminal when a subshell executes another program?**".

A few notes:

1. I need to use `exec` for its `-a` switch, which changes the zeroth argument of the process.  I would appreciate an alternative to `exec` to do just this, but I don't know of any, and now this behavior got me curious.
2. Of course, I need a subshell because I want my script to continue.  Again, any alternative would be welcome.  Is `exec` in a subshell even a good thing to do?
3. `time`'ing a subshell in general works fine, so it really has to do with `exec`.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?  I'm not sure where to begin in any of the reference materials, `exec` descriptions are pretty terse.

**Update:**  Actually, I was just "lucky" with `time` here being the bash builtin.  It doesn't parse at all with `/usr/bin/time` or with any other process:

```
$ env (exec -a foo echo hello)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `exec'
```

Actually this makes sense, we can't pass a subshell as an argument.  Any idea how to do this any other way?

**Update:**  To summarize, we have four good answers here, all different, and potentially something lacking:

1. Use actual filesystem links (hard or symbolic) that bash will use by default and `time` normally. Credits to hek2mgl.

   `ln $(which echo) foo && time ./foo hello && rm foo`
2. `fork` for `time` using bash and `exec` using a bash subshell without special syntax.

   `time bash -c 'exec -a foo echo hello'`
3. `fork` for `time` using bash but `exec` using a tiny wrapper.

   `time launch -a foo echo hello`
4. `fork` and `exec` for `time` using bash with special syntax. Credits to sjnarv.

   `time { (exec -a foo echo hello); }`

I *think* that solution 1 has the less impact on `time` as the timer doesn't have to count the `exec` in the "proxy" program, but isn't very practical (many filesystem links) nor technically ideal. In all other cases, we actually `exec` two times: once to load the proxy program (subshell for 2 and 4, wrapper for 3), and once to load the actual program. This means that `time` will count the second `exec`. While it can be extremely cheap, `exec` actually does filesystem lookups which can be pretty slow (especially if it searches through `PATH`, either itself with `exec*p` or if the proxy process does).

So, the only clean way (as far as what the answers of this question covered) would be to patch bash to modify its `time` keyword so that it can `exec` while setting the zeroth argument to a non-zero value. It would probably look like `time -a foo echo hello`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is based on the `wait` system call. From the `time` man page

> Most  information shown by time is derived from the wait3(2) system call.

This will only work if `time` is the father process of the command to be executed. But `exec` creates a completely new process.

As time requires `fork()` and `wait()` I would not attach too much attention on that zeroth argument of `exec` (what is useful, of course). Just create a symbolic link and then call it like:

```
time link_name > your.file 2>&1 &
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  The problem with your suggestion though is that I can't use the `-a` switch of bash `exec`.  I'm beginning to think that I'll have to write a C wrapper for this.

Comment: Why not? you can use -a

Comment: Well yes but then it would change `time`'s zeroth argument instead of that of the command in question (I use `echo` here just as an example, obviously), which defeats the purpose of using `exec` to begin with.

Comment: Ok, understood. is it ok for you to have to output of the command in a file?

Comment: I guess I could output to a named pipe, although it'd be extra nice if it was a normal pipe (managed by bash).  Also see my update to the question.

Comment: @user2266481 I'm currently struggeling with this (named pipe is no problem but anonymous is)

Comment: @user2266481 I would suggest something like this `exec 3> <(exec -a test /usr/bin/time sleep 1 2>&1)` .. But a `cat <&3` isn't working after that

Comment: Sorry I think you're still changing `time`'s zeroth argument.  I'm also thinking of invoking a new subshell without using bash's syntax: `time bash -c 'exec -a foo echo bar'`.  This works, but I think the overhead might make these numbers useless.  Actually, even using bash's syntax, the overhead might be too great, and it's not like one can time `exec` directly.  I think we might be looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: The simple answer is: time requires `fork()` and `wait()` I would not attach so much importance on that zeroth argument. Just use a symbolic link and `time linkname your.file 2>&1 &`

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot for your help. I actually come from a solution with lots of filesystem links which was not very maintainable and was trying to move away from it.  I'll write a C wrapper when I get some free time, I think it should merely `fork`s and `execv`s using an argument to replace `argv[0]`, just like you said.  I would still have a problem then for `time` specifically, in that the parent `time` process would obtain stats from the wrapper process and not the child;  I guess I'd need a special wrapper for `time` as well.

Comment: @user2266481 I'll think about this too.

Comment: Wrote it, see other answer. Since the wrapper is a normal program (as opposed to a shell builtin), the shell will fork itself normally to execute it, so there is no need for a proxy process. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the timer's output disappears. I think it (the timer) was running in the
sub-shell overlaid by the exec.

Here's a different invocation. Perhaps this produces what you expected initially:

```
$ time { (exec -a foo echo hello); }
```

Which for me emits:

```
hello

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Nice catch! Actually, `time` here is not an executable, nor is it a shell builtin - it's a shell *keyword*, which means it has special syntax, and in this case I think you're right in that the shell runs the timer in the subshell (which makes sense since it is the subshell process that retrieves status info for the child).  I had no idea one could `time` a compound command this way; this has the effect of forcing the shell to time the subshell process (and not the child). Thanks! Note though that because of this, `/usr/bin/time` the executable wouldn't work with this method.

Comment: Regarding use of /usr/bin/time, right - that would syntactically be a simple command list in the shell's terms, so something without all them fancy braces and parentheses should work: `/usr/bin/time bash -c 'exec -a foo echo hello'`

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up writing that tiny C wrapper, which I call `launch`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(const int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int opt;
    char *zeroth = NULL;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "a:")) != -1)
        if (opt == 'a')
            zeroth = optarg;
        else
            abort();

    if (optind >= argc) abort();
    argv += optind;
    const char *const program = *argv;
    if (zeroth) *argv = zeroth;
    return execvp(program, argv);
}
```

I obviously simplified it to emphasize only what's essential. It essentially works just like `exec -a`, except that since it is not a builtin, the shell will fork normally to run the `launch` program as a separate process.  There is thus no issue with `time`.

The `test` program in the following sample output is a simple program that only outputs its argument vector, one argument per line.

```
$ ./launch ./test hello world
./test
hello
world
$ ./launch -a foo ./test hello world
foo
hello
world
$ time ./launch -a foo ./test hello world
foo
hello
world

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
$ ./launch -a foo -- ./test -g hello -t world
foo
-g
hello
-t
world
```

The overhead should be minimal: just what's necessary to load the program, parse its single and optional argument, and manipulate the argument vector (which can be mostly reused for the next `execvp` call).

The only issue is that I don't know of a good way to signal that the wrapper failed (as opposed to the wrapped program) to the caller, which may happen if it was invoked with erroneous arguments.  Since the caller probably expects the status code from the wrapped program and since there is no way to reliably reserve a few codes for the wrapper, I use `abort` which is a bit more rare, but it doesn't feel appropriate (nor does it make it all OK, the wrapped program may still abort itself, making it harder for the caller to diagnose what went wrong).  But I digress, that's probably not interesting for the scope of this question.

**Edit:** just in case, the C compiler flags and feature test macros (gcc/glibc):

```
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
```

Comment: I see you made it :) I'm a little bit tired for today will have a closer look tomorrow..